# Премиум эмодзи для телеграмм-бота на Python

Tags: telegram, telebot

Есть ли возможность отправлять через телеграмм-бота новые премиум эмодзи (анимированные)? И если да, то как это прописать в коде?

Comment: Использую telebot

Comment: Нет. Такой возможности на сейчас нету.

Comment: По всей видимости нельзя(
Надеюсь добавят возможность